# I'm exporting contacts from Outlook 2007 to CSV file and getting question marks instead of characters

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, csv, utf-8

I need to create a CSV file that includes my Outlook 2007 contacts.
The contacts include English and Hebrew (UTF-8) characters as well.
When I export the contacts into a CSV file (Windows - with quotes) I get "???????" instead of Hebrew characters.

I read about it and already tried two ways.

First I imported the CSV file into Access and from Access export into Excel. That doesn't work because I get a .xlsx file with the Hebrew characters, but not CSV so it doesn't help me.

I also tried this: [copy from xlsx to csv](http://amirshay.blogspot.co.il/2007/04/import-cvs-file-with-hebrew-chars-to.html)
It doesn't work either.

Does anyone have a lead on this?